# preg_match if statement does only go into else part

Tags: php, regex

My code is as followed:

```
 public function validateTIME($param) 
    {
        $item = $param->Item;  
        $value = $item->configValue->TextBox->Text;

            if(preg_match('^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$', "$value"))
            {
                echo 'nice';    
            }


            else{ echo "$value";
                  echo 'wrong';
                }   
    }
```

My question is why it does only go into the else part and not in the if one.
The regex pattern is HH:MM (Hour=H Minute=M) and the pattern is ok.

Comment: use // in preg_match

Comment: If you do not get a warning on this you have to turn warnings and notices on while developing, or check your logs. This should throw a warning

Comment: i do have warnigs etc. on but it isnt an error it is only going to the else part

Comment: This code of yours [will produce a warning](https://ideone.com/YhW1Vl).

Comment: ok thats why im currently working on a project that i didnt developed so idk why it isnt throwing a warning

Comment: but why this question gets downvoted isnt clear to me i think the question as a question is good. its a duplicate yeh but because i didnt get a warning i couldnt know that...

Comment: You can shorten your regex to `^([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this  with //

```
if(preg_match('/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/', "$value"))
            {
                echo 'abcdefg';    
            }
```

for more